# Does sparse matrix multiplication in tensorflow uses GPU?(cuSparse?)

Tags: tensorflow, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to do sparse matrix multiplication using tensorflow.

But, when I saw the sparse_matmul_op.cc file, it seemed that it did not launch any cuda kernels, such as cuBlas or cuSparse.

Is it computed on CPU? not GPU?

Comment: Did you figure it out, Sungjun?